# Can you install multiple Visual Studio 2015 Test Agents on a single computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, tfs, automated-tests

I think I know the answer to this question but I haven't found anything particularly definitive.

TFS 2015

I have many very simple tests that need to be run in a distributed fashion. However from my understanding, I can either go parallel at the assembly level (which is ridiculous) or I can set multiple test agents in the runsettings file and distribute tests that way. I'd prefer not to have to spin up 10 tiny VMs but rather a one or two respectable sized VMs instead with multiple instances of the VSTA.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: What kind of tests are you running?

Comment: @AdrianHHH - Functional Tests for browser testing powered by Selenium and SpecFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Agents are mainly for running Functional Tests that have automated UI interaction. These Test, which require desktop interaction can only be run one at a rime per VM.

If you are talking about Automated Tests that do not have dektop interaction then you can use Team Build, add the Run Visual Studio Tests and tick the Parallel option.

[image]

Although the screenshots are from VSTS this option is the same in TFS 2015. There is no support for parallel tests in the old legacy Xaml Builds.

Comment: Test agents are also used by Visual Studio Load Tests, where each agent computer simulates many users. The text *"Test Agents are only for running Functional Tests ..."* is wrong.

Comment: @MrHinsh - Thanks for taking the time to respond. These are functional tests but they need to pass the burden to Selenium Grid for browser testing. Effectively, this makes them unit tests because the tests themselves don't have any immediate UI interaction. With that said, it's my understanding that the "Run in Parallel" option only applies to tests at an Assembly level. Is that correct? If I have all of my tests in a single assembly, then won't the tests run in sequence?

Comment: No to my understanding. This feature explicitly runs Unit Tests inside the same assemble in parallel.

Comment: @MrHinsh - It does appear to be at the Assembly level. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/. Either way, thank you for taking the time and thanks for your input!